# Use registerField in PyQt

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

I'm trying to use the registerField of QWizardPage class, but the documentation of PyQt does not help not providing examples. I did it thoroughly following documentation:

```
@pyqtSignature("QString")
def on_nome1_textChanged(self, text):
    self.registerField("nome1", QLineEdit, text, textChanged())
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 37, in on_nome1_textChanged
    self.registerField("nome1", QLineEdit, text, textChanged())
NameError: global name 'textChanged' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The docs provide two complete examples:  [License Wizard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-dialogs-licensewizard-example.html) and [Class Wizard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-dialogs-classwizard-example.html) (there's also [Trivial Wizard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-dialogs-trivialwizard-example.html), but that doesn't use `registerField`).

Answer (score 2):

You're suppose to create a widget before registering it as a field. Something like this:

```
myLineEdit=QtGui.QLineEdit()
myWizardPage.registerField("name",myLineEdit)
```

According to the [QT Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwizardpage.html#registerField), you don't need more arguments if you're using a `QLineEdit`:

> QWizard knows the most common Qt widgets. For these (or their
>   subclasses), you don't need to specify a property or a changedSignal.

---

You might have another issue. From the name of the method `on_nome1_textChanged`, I'm guessing the code registers the field "name" whenever the corresponding `lineEdit` text changes.

This is not how fields are meant to be use. The field is associated to the widget itself, not just it's current value. You should register the widget `lineEdit` as the field "name" only once. Then, whenever the `lineEdit` text changed, the field will also changed. To access the current value of the `lineEdit` in any page of the wizard, you just do:

```
textInLineEdit=myWizard("name")
```

Comment: The widget, it already exists, I just did not put in question code. I read this part of the documentation, but I did not know how to put on python. I changed the part you did `myWizardPage.registerField("name", myLineEdit)` using `self.registerField("name", self.nome1)` and it worked. But in the `textInLineEdit = myWizard("name")`, what would be the `myWizard`?

Comment: A `QWizardPage` should be a page of a `QWizard`, which I named `myWizard`.  Fields are not only accessible on the page where they are defined, they are also accessible on every pages of the `QWizard`